# Why Is Pudlak's relation on the family of one- or two-element subsets of a set transitive?

Tags: co.combinatorics, lattice-theory

The following comes from Definition 2 in Pavel Pudlak, "A new proof of the congruence lattice representation theorem," *Algebra Universalis* **6** (1976), 269-275.

Let $X$ be a set.  Let $F$ be a family of functions from $X$ to itself containing the identity map and closed under composition.

Define a binary relation on the family of one- or two-element subsets of $X$ as follows.  Let $a,b,c,d\in X$.  We will say that $\{a,b\}$ *dominates* $\{c,d\}$ if there are $n\in\mathbb N_0$, $u_0,\dots,u_n\in X$, and $f_1,\dots,f_n\in F$ such that $u_0=c$, $u_n=d$, and $\{f_i(a),f_i(b)\}=\{u_{i-1},u_i\}$ for $i=1,\dots,n$.

Why is domination transitive?

Comment: Because if $\{a,b\}$ dominates $\{c,d\}$ and $\{c,d\}$ dominates $\{e,h\}$ then you can compose the two functions which exist for each pair to get a third function which allows the domination of $\{a,b\}$ towards $\{e,h\}$.

Comment: @Ethan Splaver Thank you for your comment.  When I try to write out a proof using the composition, it is not so clear. The issue is that we don't know whether $f_i(a)=u_{i-1}$ or $u_i$.

Comment: @Tri It might be either, but why should that matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t see what the problem is supposed to be; you just compose the functions witnessing the two domination relations in the obvious way:

Fix $c=u_0,\dots,u_n=d$ and $f_1,\dots,f_n\in F$ such that $\{f_i(a),f_i(b)\}=\{u_{i-1},u_i\}$  for each $i=1,\dots,n$.

Fix $e=v_0,\dots,v_m=f$ and $g_1,\dots,g_m\in F$ such that $\{g_j(c),g_j(d)\}=\{v_{j-1},v_j\}$  for each $j=1,\dots,m$.

Then the fact that $\{a,b\}$ dominates $\{e,f\}$ is witnessed by the sequence
$$e=v_0=w_{1,0},w_{1,1},\dots,w_{1,n}=v_2=w_{2,0},w_{2,1},\dots,w_{m,n}=v_m=f,$$
where
$$w_{j,i}=\begin{cases}g_j(u_i)&\text{if }g_j(c)=v_{j-1}\text{ and }g_j(d)=v_j,\\
g_j(u_{n-i})&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
We have $\{w_{j,i-1},w_{j,i}\}=\{h_{j,i}(a),h_{j,i}(b)\}$, where
$$h_{j,i}=\begin{cases}g_j\circ f_i&\text{if }g_j(c)=v_{j-1}\text{ and }g_j(d)=v_j,\\
g_j\circ f_{n+1-i}&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
is in $F$ as it is closed under composition.

Comment: The "$v_2$" should be "$v_1$", but thank you.